# Powerpoint VBA - Autofit columns

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm really a beginner at vba, but I've been puzzling around how to make it work. I'm creating a powerpoint presentation with Excel vba, based on data in an excel sheet a table is created on a slide in a newly created powerpoint presentation. I've got the table formatting done, which is a real hassle, by going over each individual cell and formatting them (looping, but still)....

The only thing missing is the individual column width. Based on the input data some columns might change in width,

Because of this reason I would like to have an autofit on the columns only. The rows should remain 1 line in height. But the column width should adapt to whatever would be necessary to keep the row height on 1 line.

> ```
> Dim PPTtable1 As PowerPoint.Shape
> With PPTtable1
>     .Left = 350
>     .Top = 150
>     .Width = 758
>     .table.Columns(1).Width = Auto
>     .table.Columns(2).Width = Auto
>     .table.Columns(3).Width = Auto
> End With
> ```

This would turn the columns in the smallest possible width by stretching the height of the cells. Basically what I need is the function of double clicking on the side border of a column, and it will automatically fit to the correct width.

EDIT:
Maybe this would be interesting and important to know the order of the code:

1. Table is created
2. Format of the individual cells (bold, italic, size, font, etc...)
3. Data is filled in from an excel sheet
4. Trying to autosize the column

Comment: If you find out how to auto fit the columns, please post it here.  The one problem that you will have is that as the columns autofit and get bigger the table could become larger than the slide.  Not sure how you make sure the table doesn't grow too big.